# SQLiteDatabase locked after any insert "SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)"

Tags: android, sqlite, select, insert, journal

As I changed the android version and the path from externalized to the default database-folder, I don't know where the error come from.
I found that the reason might be problems accessing the journal file is locked (it is created by the program).

the "test" is reading data and if it exists it updates and if not it inserts. This is done in a loop while reading lines from a file. For testing purpose i simplified it but the error is the same.

```
package ...;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
public class test {
    public test(SQLiteDatabase MyDB)
    {
        MyDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable (mytext TEXT, number INT PRIMARY KEY)", new String[] {});
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String[] ColArray = { "any text", String.valueOf(i) };
            Cursor readCursor = MyDB.rawQuery("SELECT mytext FROM testtable WHERE number=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(i) });
            if (!readCursor.moveToNext()) // Error when executing moveToNext
/*
    In the 2nd time it runs over this point an Error occurs:
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
    I need to remove the journal file to be able to connect to the database it again - the change made by the Insert/Update is successfully saved!
*/          {
                readCursor.close();
                MyDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO testtable (mytext, number) VALUES(?, ?)", ColArray);
            }
            else {
                readCursor.close();
                MyDB.execSQL("UPDATE testtable SET mytext=? WHERE number=?", ColArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyDB is a valid DB-Connection.
1) The Table is created
2) The Table is READ but Line 1 is not found
2a) READ again is possible until now if the read is closed.
3) Line 1 is INSERTED
4) when trying to READ again (the line 2 would not be found, too), moving the cursor fails.

The journalfile need to be deleted manually or the app will fail to start again when trying to connect.

Please Help! Thank you.

Comment: testing on an API9 (2.3.4) device, the same code works without any errors.
the device with errors has a android version API16 (4.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the specialized insert and update methods.

In the documentation of the  [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) it says for execSQL:

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

There are specialized methods for insert and update with similar names. I guess, that there is some problem generated, when the unspecific "execSQL" statement is used.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it after hours of testing.

possibly the sqlite version is different in the old and new system... i changed the rom again - for some reason, this time i didn't copy the databasefile into the data-folder. Instead i let the program create a empty database and imported the data from text by the program itself from a csv-export.

I currently don't know if the problem was within the rom or (what seem to be the reason in my opinion) i created the problem by using the origin database which might be read and writeable but has problems when the journalfile should get processed. if somebody has an equal problem, he should try to create a new empty database in the new system.